# JS file doesn't link with Pug

Tags: javascript, pug

Can't link my js file to my pug browser console shows

```
The script from “http://localhost:3000/script.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
2 signin
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:3000/script.js”. signin:1:1
```

I've tried doing this with script tags but my js code has some errors I guess and I can't see those errors unless the code is in a different file.

this is my pug file

```
script(type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js")
script( type= 'text/javascript',src="./script.js")


form( id='formSignIn')
    div.form-group
      label(for='name') Id:
      input#name.form-control(type='text', placeholder='id' name='name')
    div.form-group
      label(for='pw') Password:
      input#password.form-control(type='password', name='password')
      button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit', id='submit') Sign In
```

this is my js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("hi");

        var name,password;
        // $("#submit").click(function(){
            name= $("#name").val();
            password=$("#password").val();
            console.log("$$$$$$$$$$$$$", name, password)
            $.post("/login", {name: name, password: password} ,function(data){
                console.log("AJAx");
            });
            console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
            localStorage.setItem('user',name);
    }
```

Comment: In pug templates, indentation is used to put elements inside each other. I don't think you'll want either the 2nd script or the form inside the 1st script.

Comment: oh my bad, didn't format the question correctly.

This is how it actually is https://github.com/BigDaddy-Zephyr/Hacker-news/blob/feature/views/signin.pug

Comment: I see; the main problem is that your script.js needs to be moved into the `public` folder. The path you state in the pug file is the browser path, not the file system path. Leave it like it is or change it to `/index.js`. (Everything in the public folder ends up in the document root.) Next you need to look at pug's `extend`/`block` so your views create proper HTML.

Comment: You should also add a `.gitignore` file and add `node_modules` to it, these don't belong in a repository.

Comment: Tried doing with index.js thing, doesn't work. Tied putting it in public folder gave src="/public/index.js" didn't work as well. console on browser shows the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write `/script.js`. Also no, don't put `public` into the path. Server-side `/public/` = client-side `/`

Comment: saved script.js in public/javascript/ changed src='/script.js' in pug , same errors.

Comment: Why did you change it? If you move `script.js` to `public/javascript/`, you need `src='/javascript/script.js'`. Again, the contents of public is the document root. If `script.js` is directly in the public folder, it will appear at http://localhost:3000/script.js If you move it into a `javascript` folder in public, it will appear at http://localhost:3000/javascript/script.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where is your index.js file (or app.js whatever your main server file is called)?

You need to set up your public folder, and put your script.js file in there.

EXAMPLE index.js file (or your main file that you are running as your server)

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()    
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001
// static folder
app.use(express.static('public'))
// load view engine
// app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'view'))
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
// listening
app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`))
```

You see the app.use(express.static('public')) line? This set your server to use your public folder. You create a public folder in your root folder. Put your script.js file in that public folder.

Now in your pug file, you can load your script.js file in there with the tag
`script(src='/script.js')`

You DONT need to set it as '/public/script.js' BECAUSE you already set your public folder as the source. You just need to point to the file, which is just it's just '/script.js'

Comment: Thank you. I forgot that all asset files should be placed in a folder, which is by convention named public. Using the built-in middleware function named express.static(), then the application will serve all asset files : html, css, including javascript files, from that public folder. Problem solved. I can now proceed to create a full-stack, standalone application using Node+Express at backend and React at frontend like I did with PHP+Laravel and React. Thanks again.